# Mysql ругается на Declare в триггере

Tags: mysql, триггер

Создаю триггер через phpMyAdmin. Тело триггера:

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE ids INT;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE notify = '1';
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
IF NEW.product_price < OLD.product_price THEN
    OPEN cur;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO ids;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO notifications (notify_dateDelivered, notify_title, notify_body, notify_userID) VALUES (NOW(), 'Снизилась цена на ' + OLD.product_name, OLD.product_name + ' теперь можно купить по цене ' + NEW.product_price + 'р.!', ids);
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
  END IF;
```

Ответ MySQL:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; DECLARE ids INT; DECLARE cur CURSOR FO' at line 1

Почему?

Comment: Может, потому что `DECLARE done INT`, а `DEFAULT FALSE` - это уже не INT?

Comment: *Тело триггера:* Вот не надо обрезков. Давайте ВЕСЬ код.

Comment: Обрезков чего?) Это и есть весь код триггера. В phpMyAdmin они создаются без вводных строк

Comment: Igor Dyshlenko, изменил на DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE; такая же ошибка

Comment: Все решилось. Нужно было обернуть код в begin end; Странно для phpMyadmin